# Moon, Earth and the Sun

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, solar-system

How to prove that the geometric locus of the points where the attractive forces of the Sun and the Moon are of equal intensity is a sphere of radius $ r =  \frac{R  \sqrt{Mm}}{M-m } $, where $M$ is mass of Sun, and $m$ is mass of Earth, $R$ distance Earth-Sun.

Comment: Search terms: “Hill sphere,” “Lagrange points.” Beware that Hill’s region is only approximately spherical; three-body gravity is chaotic.

Comment: Do you know how to write the magnitudes of the two forces at an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$? If so, set them equal.

Comment: *attractive forces of the Sun and the Moon* If you are considering the forces due to the Sun and the Moon, don’t you mean that $m$ is the mass of the Moon and $R$ is the Moon-Sun distance?